# Why does this moment diff function return 0 instead of 1

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Returns 0 months but this should be 1 month as from the docs I see that inclusive dates from one month to the next count as a month.

```
console.log(moment('2020-11-06T00:00:00+00:00').diff(moment('2020-10-06T21:22:21.2976559+00:00'), 'months'))
```

Comment: What does `console.log(moment('2020-11-06T00:00:00+00:00').diff(moment('2020-10-06T00:00:00+00:00'), 'months'))` print?

Comment: the way I see it, if you add a month to `2020-10-06T21:22:21....` you get `2020-11-06T21:22:21....` which is after `2020-11-06T00:00:00....` therefore 0 months

Comment: @RoboRobok it prints 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at what you're comparing.

```
2020-10-06T21:22:21.2976559+00:00
2020-11-06T00:00:00+00:00
```

The second date's time is at 00:00. The first date's time is at 21:22:21. You're just shy of a full month.

Normalize the time and it'll work.

```js
console.log(moment('2020-11-06T00:00:00').diff(moment('2020-10-06T00:00:00'), 'months'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Snow, how can I normalise the time if I don't control the dates that might be coming in e.g. if I'm making a function which takes dates.

Comment: If you're not concerned about sub-day differences, you can drop them and only pass into Moment the dates (eg `2020-11-06`)

Comment: The dates are coming from an external source which provides them in the full format though with times. I can't seem to find a way to extract the date out and still use the diff function. Any ideas?

Comment: Like I said, drop the time portion out and just use the plain dates. Remove the T and everything that comes after.

Comment: Did you mean by using something like substr? or does moment provide a way?

Comment: You can do it any way you want, it's trivial. Eg `str.split('T')[0]` then pass that to `moment`

Answer (score 0):

I found this in their docs https://momentjs.com/docs/

> *Note: Moments are created at evaluation time, so moment().diff(moment()) may not always return 0. See this GitHub issue for more details.*

The GitHub link is:
https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/5195

Answer (score -2):

First, moment is deprecated and not recommended to be used in new projects https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Month/year diff discussion can be seen here: https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/571

If you remove the time information, it will return 1 as expected: `console.log(moment('2020-11-06').diff(moment('2020-10-06'), 'months'));`. This looks like a bug to me, but I guess it just the way moment is expected to work